# Ansible and MariaDB. Can't install MariaDB through playbook

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, mariadb, ansible

I'm sorry for my poor English.

I'm stuck at installing MariaDB server to vagrant machine. I have the following:

```
- name: install mariadb addons
  apt: pkg=software-properties-common state=latest
  sudo: yes

- name: add mariadb key
  apt_key: url=http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xcbcb082a1bb943db
  sudo: yes

- name: add mariadb repository
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://mirror.timeweb.ru/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu precise main'
  sudo: yes
  notify:
    - update repositories
```

After `vagrant provision` I get the following:

```
TASK: [install mariadb addons] ************************************************ 
ok: [192.168.0.3]

TASK: [add mariadb key] ******************************************************* 
ok: [192.168.0.3]

TASK: [add mariadb repository] ************************************************ 
failed: [192.168.0.3] => {"failed": true}
msg: Could not import python modules: pycurl. Please install python-pycurl package.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

What I doing wrong? How can I install mariaDB without installing python-pycurl package?

Comment: Why don't you want to install `python-pycurl`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your ansible playbook file

```
- name: install python-pycurl
  apt: pkg=python-pycurl state=latest
  sudo: yes
```

Or if you have `python-pip` installed

```
- name: install curl-config
  apt: pkg=libcurl4-openssl-dev state=latest
  sudo: yes

- name: install python-pycurl
  pip: name=pycurl state=latest
  sudo: yes
```